# Has anyone ever done max damage with Chocobuckle?

Tags: final-fantasy-7

In 1997’s *Final Fantasy VII* there is a learnable skill named “[Chocobuckle](https://finalfantasy.fandom.com/wiki/Chocobuckle)” which does unblockable damage based on the number of time the player has escaped a battle. Specifically it does 1 damage for every escaped battle during the game, up to the damage limit of 9999.

Needless to say, in theory this is incredibly powerful, but starting and then escaping nearly ten thousand battles would be utterly tedious. The only reason I could imagine for someone to go through this process would be to show others that they'd done it. It would be so dull and time consuming that it basically wouldn't have any benefit to playing through the game.

Has anyone actually put in the time to legitimately achieve this maximum unblockable damage?

---

I realise that this number could be manipulated on PC versions of the game, but there's nothing remarkable about cheating to do a large amount of damage, this could be done many other ways. I'm only really interested in whether or not someone has done it by escaping.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Apparently yes.

I found this video on YouTube from [Velius99](https://www.youtube.com/channel/UCKBuZtTGhhppoZJzgPL8GaQ), he shows all the main game bosses being defeated using only Chocobuckle, and starting from a certain point the skill deals 9999.

Comment: Even if it was deleted, I'm still wondering: why the downvote?